# Operators#lift: good idea for MDC logging?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, mdc

Project Reactor documentation suggests the following pattern for MDC logging:

```
.doOnEach(logOnNext(r -> LOG.debug("found restaurant {} for ${}", r.getName(), r.getPricePerPerson())))
```

To avoid having to wrap each logging call, would a custom subscriber, populating the MDC from the currentContext before each signal, added using `Hooks.onEachOperator(Operators.lift(...)`) be a good idea?

My main conerns are:

1.) The cost of populating the MDC before every signal, even if there is no logging happening.

2.) Operator fusion: Does `Operators.lift(...)` on each operator effectively disable operator fusion? Attempting a quick test with `StepVerifier#expectFusion` seems to indicate that. If this is true, how much of a performance hit is this, in practice?

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the approach that was initially taken by Sleuth, via `Hooks.onEachOperator`. However, this is *very* costly and probably not worth it if you only need logging/MDC on a subset of operations in you reactive pipeline. Not to mention that this approach not only impacts reactive steps defined by you, but also any other library / framework.

The recommendation is there for a reason: better control, less impact and a more explicit approach.

Comment: any cost-effective way to log in using MDC?

Comment: threads in Reactor can and will be reused by multiple Flux that run concurrently (for example, two different `Flux` that use the `Schedulers.parallel()`) so it is important that any `ThreadLocal` (which the MDC is based on) are set then cleared around each `onNext` signal. You could have a helper method that populates the MDC, performs the logging and clears the MDC, all in a `doOnEach` operator.

Comment: @SimonBaslé Is there a reason not to use `transformDeferredContextual` to create a custom `flatMap` implementation that sets MDC using the context that becomes available? This seems similar to the approach discussed here without affecting every pipeline

Comment: This is for a Spring webflux application which acts mostly as a proxy btw. I would think that the `Hooks.onEachOperator` would also not be an issue given that our reactive chains are performance bound by network operations anyway. If the use of that hook affects other libraries and frameworks though, it's harder to be confident that it doesn't have a significant impact on their internal operations